postgres database connected but table relations not found when running nodejs typescript api in a docker container
i wrote a basic api with typescript in nodejs which runs fine when started with the start script "node dist/index.js", but after dockerizing it, the database seems to have been connected although there are no tables accessible
server logs
[7/10/2024, 1:26:07 PM] [INFO] [0] [index.ts]  Server is running on http://localhost:3000
[7/10/2024, 1:26:13 PM] [INFO] [0] [db.config]  Connected to the db
[7/10/2024, 1:26:13 PM] [ERROR] [0] [operator.signup.controller] error: relation "operators" does not exist
    at /app/node_modules/pg-pool/index.js:45:11
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  length: 108,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42P01',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: '13',
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'parse_relation.c',
  line: '1392',
  routine: 'parserOpenTable'
}

but when i logged in to docker container and connected to pg, the tables actually do exist.
docker container for pg database
github - https://github.com/aditipolkam/quicktrip
Dockerfile - using docker multi-stage build
# Stage 1: PostgreSQL
FROM postgres:15.5 AS db
COPY init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
EXPOSE 5432

# Stage 2: Node.js build
FROM node:20.5 AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# Stage 3: Node.js production
FROM node:20.5 AS production
WORKDIR /app
COPY ssl-tls-key.pem ssl-tls-key.pem
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install --only=production
ARG NODE_ENV
COPY .env.${NODE_ENV} .env
COPY --from=build /app/dist ./dist
CMD ["node", "dist/index.js"]


docker-compose.yml
services:
  db:
    build:
      context: .
      target: db
    env_file:
      - .env.${NODE_ENV}
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U $${POSTGRES_USER}"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

  app:
    build:
      context: .
      target: production
      args:
        NODE_ENV: ${NODE_ENV}
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    env_file:
      - .env.${NODE_ENV}
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

volumes:
  db_data:


init.sql
CREATE TABLE test_table (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE operators (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    contact INT NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

build and start docker containers - NODE_ENV=local docker-compose up --build -d
NODE_ENV can change - local | staging
.env.local
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_HOST=db      #was localhost earlier but changed to db for docker container execution  
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgresdb
POSTGRES_DB=quicktrip
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
SALT_ROUNDS=10


Is there anything interesting in docker-compose logs db?  In particular, /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d scripts only run the very first time a database container is created, if its data volume is empty, and you may see a warning to that effect.  Application-specific CREATE TABLE statements are often better to run via a database-migration framework, which can both incrementally add or modify tables if needed and also can run in non-Docker setups.

thank you, i wrote a script that runs on project startup to check if tables exist and if not to create them, but i still have a doubt as to why the pre-existing tables were not found when queried through the api

You should execute you entry sql not just copy
FROM postgres:15.5 AS db
COPY init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
EXPOSE 5432

command for execute init.sql like this
 $  psql -U <DATABASE_USERNAME> -d <DATABASE_NAME> < init.sql


The postgres image startup will run all of the scripts in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d on first startup; you can't RUN a psql command because the database isn't running and its data store doesn't exist.
